How do I download wheels for the allosaurus python module?
I'm having trouble understanding how to download wheels for a Python project.  I need to build a set of wheels for a Blender addon - Blender has recently changed it's addon requirements, so I need to build wheels for it now.
Anyhow, I want to use the allosaurus package.  It has dependencies on a lot of other packages such as scipy and torch.  Some of the dependencies have platform specific binary distros, while other dependencies are source only.
If I use the pip wheel allosaurus -w ./wheels command, this downloads the wheels and dependencies, but only has the binaries for Windows (I'm working on a Windows machine).  I also need to download the full set of wheels for Mac and Linux too.  Unfortunately, when I try pip download allosaurus --dest ./wheels-mac --only-binary=:all: --python-version=3.11 --platform=macosx_11_0_arm64, it only downloads one very out of date version of allosaurus.
I've tried downloading the wheels for the dependencies independently, however scipy on the Mac only has macosx versions 14, 12 and 10 available, while torch has macosx 11.  I don't know if these are compatible.  And when I try to download some of the source only dependencies, I get the zip file.  I'm also getting multiple versions of numpy downloaded.
I don't really understand what I'm doing.  How can I download directories for Mac, Linux and Windows distros, with all the wheels they need?

There is only a wheel 1.0.2 from 2021

When I run the mac specific command above, it downloads version 0.0.3 of allosaurus.  Pip is also able to find more than a dozen different versions of allosaurus.

Cross-platform pip downloading works pretty badly for packages that only have source distributions (no wheels) or source wheels (multi-version, universal). My advice is to run Hyper-V or Qemu virtual machines emulating your destination processor, install destination platforms (OS, Python version) in it, run pip download and move downloaded wheels to the destination hosts.
In addition to allosaurus dependencies I also recommend to download and move build tools. I.e. the entire command in emulators should be
pip download --dest ./wheels allosaurus pip setuptools wheel

